# Проверить список на непрерывное возрастание чисел и получить

Tags: python, python-3.6

Создавал предыдущий вопрос но не совсем уточнил точные действия. И так у нас есть список из чисел:

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5,100,214,411,41]
OUT: True, MAX: 5
```

Нам требуется проверить, если в этом списке есть 5 чисел которые нарастают непрерывно, то есть - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, а так же вывести то число до какого идет непрерывное возрастание, в нашем случае 5
Так же списки могут быть разными, к примеру у нас будет такой список:

```
num = [22,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,41,44,200]
OUT: True, MAX: 8
```

Тут мы видим что нарастание идет уже из 8 цифр, нам требовалось проверить наростают ли 5 цифр, в этом случае мы должны получить что непрерывно наростают у нас 3,4,5,6,7 (то есть получаем максимальное число)

Comment: Можно применить цикл for и оператор сравнения if

Comment: Во втором списке 8 таких чисел.

Comment: А может быть в списке несколько нарастающих последовательностей разной длины? Из которой из последовательностей тогда брать максимальное число? И какой длины последовательности вообще рассматриваются - от двух чисел начиная или от скольки?

Comment: @Эникейщик да может быть разной длинны, наша задача найти максимальное возрастающее число из 5

Comment: почему вы убрали галочку с моего ответа?

Comment: @Danis `for i in range(len(arr) - 5):` нужно поправить на `for i in range(len(arr) - 4):`

Comment: нет надо именно `len(arr) - 5`. Если место 5 поставить 4 то на последнем итерации мы получим массив длиной в 4, а не 5

Comment: @Danis, но если сейчас в функцию передать такой массив [1,2,3,4,5] он вернет False

Comment: @Danis или такой [23,21,22,20,19,8,1] он так же вернет False, я просто поменял на range(len(arr) - 4) и все начало работать корректно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) - 5):
        el = arr[i:i + 5]
        if el == list(range(min(el), max(el) + 1)):
            return True, el[-1]
    return False
    
print(f([22,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,41,44,200]))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> (True, 5)
> ```

---

```
def f(arr):
    arr2 = []
    for i in range(len(arr) - 5):
        el = arr[i:i + 5]
        if el == list(range(min(el), max(el) + 1)):
            arr2.append(el[-1])
            
    if arr2:
        return True, max(arr2)
    return False
    
print(f([22,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,41,44,200]))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> (True, 8)
> ```

---

Вариант где длина передаётся как параметр

```
def f(arr, n):
    for i in range(len(arr) - n):
        el = arr[i:i + n]
        if el == list(range(min(el), max(el) + 1)):
            return True, el[-1]
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
old = arr[0]
len_max = 0
len_cur = 0
for value in arr + [arr[-1] + 2]:
    if value != old + 1:
        len_max = len_cur if len_cur > len_max else len_max
        len_cur = 0
    old = value
    len_cur += 1

print(len_max >= 5, len_max)
```